# Finding The Obtuse Angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I am working on a simple force problem involving inclines. I found a reference of $48^\circ$, in the third quadrant; now, to find the obtuse angle, do I subtract that value from $270^\circ$, or do I add it to $180^\circ$?

Comment: I've just done an edit changing $48^{~o}$ to $48^\circ$ (and similarly with the other angles).  TeX is not so crude.

Comment: This is a matter that depends on the definitions used inn *this particular problem*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a diagram or slightly clearer rephrasing of the question is in order, but I think you want to do $180^{\circ} - \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle you have found.